# How do I define the priority of conditional formatting in sharepoint designer?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, conditional

Let's say if I have two conditional formatting for a list:

1. if category = cat, background color change to red
2. if location = foo, background color change to grey.

Now, if the item has the category equal to cat and location equal to foo, how does sharepoint define which back ground color should it apply to the item? I'm using sharepoint 2010 but I couldn't find any setting about the priority of conditional formatting.

Comment: which one you want to apply if both conditions are true?

Comment: @Waqas Sarwar MCSE , I want category = cat to have higher priority, so the background color should be red

Comment: i think then you need to put 3 conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 3 conditions, something like this

1. if category = cat and location = foo  background color change to red
2. if category = cat and location !=(not equal) foo  background color change to red
3. if category !=(not equal) cat and location = foo  background color change to grey

check this one to learn more about conditional formatting. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/balsharfi/archive/2011/10/20/sharepoint-lists-conditional-formatting-using-sharepoint-designer-2010.aspx

Comment: Thank you! I feel silly for asking such an obvious question now....

Comment: No question silly...so dont worry

Answer (score 1):

here is the link for conditional formatting, which may helps you for the solution
http://www.aspe-it.com/blog/2013/using-sharepoint-designer-2010/

for more:
[SharePoint 2013 Administrator Training](http://staygreenacademy.com/)